# getting "Activity has been destroyed "exception while loading single fragment for more times inside the single activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am getting the below error while I was loading Fragment inside the activity

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
03-19 14:12:48.779 12008-12008/com.ensis.sample W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2075)
03-19 14:12:48.780 12008-12008/com.ensis.sample W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:680)
03-19 14:12:48.781 12008-12008/com.ensis.sample W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:634)
03-19 14:12:48.782 12008-12008/com.ensis.sample W/System.err:     at com.ensis.sample.MainActivity.loadFragment(MainActivity.java:107)
03-19 14:12:48.783 12008-12008/com.ensis.sample W/System.err:     at com.ensis.sample.MainActivity.clickedItem(MainActivity.java:123)
03-19 14:12:48.783 12008-12008/com.ensis.sample W/System.err:     at com.ensis.sample.MyAdapter$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:42)
```

Actually I have an horizontal `recyclerview` . when I click on the `recyclerview` item I going to add the fragment inside that activity itself.

**Screenshot:-**

[image]

below is my MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CallBackInterface {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private List<String> listItems;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_id);
        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_id);

       // loadFragment(new AlphabetsFragment(), "Aa");
       //loadFragment(this, new AlphabetsFragment(), true, null, "Aa");
        loadFragment(this, new AlphabetsFragment(), false, null, "Aa");


        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.add("A");
        listItems.add("B");
        listItems.add("C");
        listItems.add("D");
        listItems.add("E");
        listItems.add("F");
        listItems.add("G");

        Log.d("tag", "============click===========" + listItems.size());
        adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public void clickedItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                loadFragment(this, new AlphabetsFragment(), false, null, "Bb");
                break;
            case 1:
                //loadFragment(new Aacf(), "Bb");
                loadFragment(this, new AlphabetsFragment(), false, null, "Bb");
                break;
            case 2:
                //loadFragment(new AlphabetsFragment(), "Cc");
                loadFragment(this, new AlphabetsFragment(), false, null, "Cc");
                break;

        }
    }
    public static void loadFragment(Context context, Fragment fragment, boolean isPopBackStack,
                                    FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener onBackStackChangedListener,
                                    String identification) {

        try {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (onBackStackChangedListener != null) {
                fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(onBackStackChangedListener);
            }
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if (isPopBackStack) {
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key", identification);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_id, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

below is my fragment code

```
alphabetText = view.findViewById(R.id.text_2aid);

Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String aplhabet = bundle.getString("key");
alphabetText.setText(aplhabet);
```

below is the adapter class code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by ensis on 03/19/2018.
*/

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
CallBackInterface interf = (CallBackInterface) new MainActivity();

public MyAdapter(List<String> listItems, Context context) {
this.listItems = listItems;
this.context = context;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, parent, false);
return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.button.setText(listItems.get(position));
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
interf.clickedItem(position);
}
});
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
Log.d("tag", "size===1===" + listItems.size());
return listItems.size();

}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public Button button;

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
super(itemView);
button
= itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
}
}
}
```

below is the xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
tools:context="com.ensis.sample.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frame_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_id"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
<!--</FrameLayout>-->


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have seen some answers related to this issue. but none of them were helped to me. Please help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: add the code for adapter class as well and activity xml also

Comment: @quicklearner , I have added adapter and xml code. please check it

Comment: also add the class where you have initialized MyAdapter

Comment: @quicklearner, please check it